# Graphics not appearing for java game

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics

I have been working on a 2D top-down (like old zelda) game in java with eclipse IDE. When I run the game during dev and after I compile it for testing it runs fine on my computer but when I run it on another computer it only shows text that I put in with code not graphics. I watched a video on adding textures to your game by TheCherno on YouTube, I followed what he said by putting it in the project's res folder and I fixed the code to get the graphics from there. I then compiled it again and to no avail it still didn't work on other computers. If you have any solutions I would be extremely happy.

Here is a Link to the eclipse project folder so you can see the code and setup:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4229589/Copy%20of%20Copy%20of%20ld48.zip

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the location of your resource folder changes when used on another computer.

It would be helpful to see the code you use to access the resource folder.

for example

If your filepath was say (inputting my username as an example):

```
C:\Users\IanMelrose\Game\Resources
```

It would not appear that way on another computer.

Comment: no, it was originally like that and I figured that out in like 2min. but it is in the project folder and the who project gets compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting all of the images, right clicking -> Build Path -> Add to build path

Can you show an example of how you reference an image in your code?